# kdb: calling parse on a list of variables

Tags: kdb

I learned from [here](https://code.kx.com/q/wp/parse-trees/#the-parse-keyword) that

> [...] in a parse tree a variable is represented by a symbol
> containing its name. Thus to distinguish a symbol or a list of symbols
> from a variable it is necessary to enlist that expression.

Given that, why does below expression evaluate to `` (enlist;`a;`b) `` instead of just `` `a`b ``?

Asking because it seems `` enlist[`a;`b]~`a`b `` is true.

```
q)parse"(a;b)"
enlist
`a
`b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you would ever want a parse tree to collapse two same-type values into a single uniform list, it would break the ability to `eval` the parse tree, e.g

```
q)a:1
q)b:1
q)
q)eval parse"(a;b)"
1 1
q)eval `a`b
'type
  [0]  eval `a`b
       ^
```

And secondly, `` (enlist;`a;`b) `` isn't the same as `` enlist[`a;`b] `` however the `value` of `` (enlist;`a;`b) `` is:

```
q)value[(enlist;`a;`b)]~enlist[`a;`b]
1b
```

So I guess it comes down to the nuanced differences between `eval` and `value`

Comment: Thanks for the example Terry - I think that makes sense. Also feel this is related to my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304802/kdb-what-is-the-type-of-parsexy

Comment: Yep, related. Parse trees shouldn't be flattened