# kdb: what is the type of parse"x[y]"?

Tags: kdb

For expression `parse"x[y]"`, I think it means a function/map/list application of `x` on argument `y`, possibly a projection. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Now entering into Q console, I get below output.

```
q)parse"x[y]"
x
y
q)l:parse"x[y]"
q)count l
2
q)type l
0h
q)l[0]
`x
q)l[1]
`y
q)type l[0]
-11h
q)type l[1]
-11h
```

#### We see `l` has type `0h`. It has length 2. Both elements have type `-11h`. Why is the list then, not of type `11h`?

Comment: As an FYI - related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66304637/kdb-calling-parse-on-a-list-of-variables/66304800

Comment: @terrylynch In general though, is it then possible for a list to contain atoms of identical types (e.g. symbol), but still for the list to have type `0h`?

Comment: In general no, it would usually collapse into a uniform list but there are always weird edge cases and grey areas! Though I don't consider this issue to be weird or an edge case, it's expected behaviour for parse tree generation

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's a parse tree signature *'type'* construct, very similar to lambda (which would be type 64). `k` recognises and evaluates expression in parse tree when object reaches call stack, de-referencing symbols-which acts like a pointer.

**TL;DR** - Step by step breakdown

1. Basic evaluation constructs

`"x[y]" ~ "x y"`

```
q)x:count
q)y: 1 2 3
q)parse "x y"  
x
y
q)x y
3
q)`x y
3
q)eval parse "x y"
3
```

Simple indexing, *'simplified'* 2nd param -> int atom:

```
q)parse "y 2"  //this nicely shows parse tree
`y
2
q)eval parse "y 2" 
3 
q)eval (`y;2)
3 
q)`y 2
3
q)y 2
3
```

Both above examples are mixed lists (0h), with actual elements following immediately - where symbols - are references. Instead with normal mixed list construct where all lenghts and types are defined later

2. Looking at serialised IPC frame helps to understand this construct

`Establish what expressions are the same`

```
q)parse["x[y]"] ~ parse "x y"
1b
q)parse["x[y]"] ~ parse "x@y"
0b
q)parse["x[y]"] ~ parse "{x y}" 
0b
```

`Compare byte frames`

```
q)-8!parse "x[y]" 
0x0100000014000000000002000000f57800f57900
q)-8!parse "x y"  
0x0100000014000000000002000000f57800f57900  
q)-8!`x`y 
0x01000000120000000b000200000078007900 
q)-8!enlist `x`y
0x01000000180000000000010000000b000200000078007900
```

`Compare parse tree output from 1st paragraph with actual obj instead of reference`

```
q)-8!parse "x y"
0x0100000014000000000002000000f57800f57900 
q)-8!parse "x 2"
0x010000001a000000000002000000f57800f90200000000000000
```

`Lambda structure to complete the list for reference`

```
q)-8!{x y}
0x010000001500000064000a00050000007b7820797d
/0x7b "{" ; 0x7d "}"
```

3. And finally the IPC frame breakdown

`` `x`y (symbol list) ``

```
q)symlist:`endian`isync`x`y`length`type`attr`msg!sums[0 1 1 1 1 4 1 1] _ -8!`x`y
q)symlist
 endian| ,0x01     (little endian)    
 isync | ,0x00 
 x     | ,0x00   
 y     | ,0x00 
 length| 0x12000000 
 type  | ,0x0b     (11h - symbol list - 1st difference)
 attr  | ,0x00  
 msg   | 0x0200000078007900
```

dig into the symlist:

```
  q)msg:`lenght`msg!sums[0 4] _ symlist`msg 
  q)msg
   lenght| 0x02000000
   msg   | 0x78007900
```

Here we can clearly see, how null terminated symbol follows length of vector immediately, due to explicit type: 0x0b - 11h - symbol list

```
  q)`char$msg`msg
   "x\000y\000"
```

`parse "x[y]"`  - parse tree breakdown

```
q)o1:`endian`isync`x`y`length`type`attr`msg!sums[0 1 1 1 1 4 1 1]_ -8!parse"x[y]"
q)o1   
 endian| ,0x01            
 isync | ,0x00   
 x     | ,0x00 
 y     | ,0x00   
 length| 0x14000000    
 type  | ,0x00   (could expect 64 - 100h lambda)
 attr  | ,0x00    
 msg   | 0x02000000f57800f57900
```

Difference from simple list:

```
   q)`lenght`type1`msg1`type2`msg2!sums[0 4 1 2 1 ] _ o1`msg
    lenght| 0x02000000
    type1 | ,0xf5        (-11h - symbol atom) - acts as a reference
    msg1  | 0x7800       null terminated "x" 
    type2 | ,0xf5        (-11h - symbol atom)
    msg2  | 0x7900       null terminated "y"  - acts as a reference
```